# Passing multiple system properties to google dataproc cluster job

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to submit a spark job on Dataproc cluster. The job needs multiple system properties. I am able to pass just one as follows:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \                                   
    --cluster <cluster_name> \
    --class <class_name> \
    --properties spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhost=127.0.0.1  \
    --jars spark_job.jar
```

How do I pass multiple properties?
I tried as follow, even this didn't work.

`--properties ^#^spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhost=127.0.0.1,-Dlimit=10`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \                                   
    --cluster <cluster_name> \
    --class <class_name> \
    --properties spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dhost=127.0.0.1 -Dlimit=10 -Dproperty_name=property_value' \
    --jars spark_job.jar
```

Comment: how top pass to the same to DataprocSubmitSparkJobOperator ??